# Python datetime module and getting current time

Tags: python, datetime

I'm a beginner in Python and I want to make a simple project to say how much time is left until Christmas.
First I had a problem with the current time:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.now()
print(now)`
```

and the error said `module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'`

Than I fixed it by doing `from datetime import datetime`
but than the calculation for the date created an error
The code:

```
from datetime import datetime
xmas = datetime.date(2020, 12, 25) - datetime.date.today()
now = datetime.now()
print(now)
```

And the error was: `Exception has occurred: TypeError descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'`
Please help me.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datetime` class is a little confusing to import because it's in a module that's also called `datetime`.  When you do `from datetime import datetime` you're importing the *class* `datetime` into the current scope and can just do `datetime.now()`.  If you just do `import datetime` you're importing the *module* `datetime` and so the class is `datetime.datetime`, making the `now` method `datetime.datetime.now()`.  Clear as mud?  :)

Further adding to the confusion, the `datetime` module has a `date` class, and the `datetime` class has a `date` method.  You're mixing the two up in your code, calling the `date` method of the `datetime` class when you mean to be constructing a `date` object.  Since you did `from datetime import datetime`, you did not import the `datetime.date` class at all.

Anyway, here's how to fix it:

```
import datetime

xmas = datetime.date(2020, 12, 25) - datetime.date.today()
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now)
```

Note that in this code, `xmas` is a `datetime.timedelta` object, and `now` is a `datetime.datetime` object.

You could also do:

```
from datetime import date, datetime

xmas = date(2020, 12, 25) - date.today()
now = datetime.now()
print(now)
```

Hopefully seeing the two examples side by side helps clarify the module vs class thing.  It's all about different levels of indirection -- in the first example the `import` statement brings in the whole module, and your code needs to specify which classes to pull out of it.  In the second example, the `from ... import` statement pulls those two classes out of the module as part of the import, and so the code can access them by those names directly.  Since the names are all so similar, you can't rely on the name to know what kind of thing you're accessing unless you really understand what exactly the import statement did.

Comment: can I ask for one more thing? Its how to calculate the time until chrismas like I did for the date. Because I'm having problems with it

Comment: `time_till_xmas = datetime(2020, 12, 25) - datetime.now()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to import it like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
```